# Differences among HTML DOM APIs

Tags: html, dom

So I have a question.
I know that I can manipulate HTML DOM through multiple APIS like
`document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByTagName` etc.
I wonder why there are so much APIs to manipulate DOM? Why can't just use `document.querySelector`？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder why there are so much APIs to manipulate DOM?

The main reason is history.

`document.querySelector` was only added recently: `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName` have been with us since the mid-1990s, but `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` were only added around 2010, but it wasn't safe to use them until after IE6, IE7 and IE8 usage dropped below some popularity threshold which wasn't until around 2013 in my experience.

Secondarily, consider that CSS wasn't widely used on Internet websites until around 1999, and even then it was only used for basic styling of text (fonts, colors, etc), CSS *couldn't* be reliably used for entire web-page layout (using only `float`!) until around 2004 (too many people were *still* using Netscape 4.x then).

> Why can't just use `document.querySelector`

You can. There's no real reason to use the other functions today.

That said, there may still be a reason to use the older functions: performance. With `querySelector` the browser has to parse the string as a CSS selector and then [build a CSS selector automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory) and then execute it, whereas the much simpler `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementById` will have straightforward implementations.

(I'll concede that by now browser-makers will have *optimized* `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` for the trivial `'elementName'` and `'#id'` selectors and have them use the same optimal path as the older functions).